# What order must column attributes be entered when using the CREATE TABLE statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use the MySQL `CREATE TABLE` command, as I enter column attributes (i.e.: data types, defaults) in a particular order, I notice that MySQL is selective to how they are exactly entered.  Which leads me to my question, when entering columns attributes into the `CREATE TABLE` command, what is the order in which columns must be entered?

i.e.: Same statement, but different order of attributes.

Statement A (Works):
 `CREATE TABLE test1 (first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, last_name varchar(50) NULL);`

Statement B (Does not work): `CREATE TABLE test1 (first_name NOT NULL varchar(50), last_name NULL varchar(50) );`

Comment: You have it correct in the first version . . . first the type then the constraints (`NOT NULL` is type of a constraint).  The `CREATE TABLE` documentation is quite clear on the order of the attributes (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).  If you need help understanding the grammar diagrams, then I'm sure that is also in the documentation.

Comment: The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) defines the correct order under the label "column_definition".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Statement A in your case.

The order in which you specify the columns doesn't matter if you're simply looking to avoid syntax errors. What matters is the order of the properties per column, and I think that's what you're really asking about.

`CREATE TABLE test1 (first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL, last_name varchar(50) NULL);`

The order for column properties is:

1. Name
2. Type
3. Constraints (such as NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

`CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size) constraint_name,
column_name2 data_type(size) constraint_name,
column_name3 data_type(size) constraint_name,
....
);`

In SQL, we have the following constraints:

**NOT NULL** - Indicates that a column cannot store NULL value

**UNIQUE** - Ensures that each row for a column must have a unique value
**PRIMARY KEY** - A combination of a NOT NULL and UNIQUE. Ensures that a column (or combination of two or more columns) have a unique identity which helps to find a particular record in a table more easily and quickly

**FOREIGN KEY** - Ensure the referential integrity of the data in one table to match values in another table

**CHECK** - Ensures that the value in a column meets a specific condition

**DEFAULT** - Specifies a default value for a column

You can read up on each of these in more detail.